# Prove that any vector v of V can be expressed in a unique way as a linear combination

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose $\{e_1, . . . , e_n\}$ is a basis of a real vector space $V$ .

Let 
$$e_{n+1} = −e_1 − ... − e_n$$

Prove that any vector $v$ of $V$ can be expressed in a unique way as a
linear combination

$$v = a_1e_1 + · · · + a_ne_n + a_{n+1}e_{n+1}$$

with coefficients $a_1, . . . , a_n, a_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $a_1 + · · · + a_n + a_{n+1} = 0$

could anyone help with this or even where to start as it is confusing me already!

Comment: Do you know that you can express $v\in V$ uniquely as $$v = b_1e_1 + ... + b_ne_{n}$$ with $b_i \in \mathbb{R}$? Do know the definition of a basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}a_ie_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}b_ie_i$. Let $c_i=a_i-b_i$ so that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}c_ie_i=0$. This gives $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}c_ie_i=-c_{n+1}e_{n+1}=c_{n+1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}e_i$. Hence $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(c_i-c_{n+1})e_i=0$. This implies $c_i=c_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Add this over $i \leq n$ and use the fact that $\sum c_i=0$ to see that $c_i=0$ for all $i$ or $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but shouldn't it be $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i=-c_{n+1}e_{n+1}$? Which proves that the linear combination is unique, but, since the statement holds $\forall v\in V$, then $v$ isn't necessarily a zero-vector.

Comment: @Invisible There was  a typo. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also show this by an explicit construction which produces unique values for the $a_i$ coefficients. Since $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ you know that there are unique real co-ordinates $b_i$ such that

$v = b_1e_1 + \dots + b_ne_n$

If you also have

$v = a_1e_n + \dots + a_ne_n + a_{n+1}e+{n+1} = (a_1-a_{n+1})e_1 + \dots + (a_n-a_{n+1})e_n$

then you can equate the co-ordinates to get

$b_1 = a_1 - a_{n+1}\\b_2 = a_2 - a_{n+1}\\ \dots \\b_n = a_n - a_{n+1}$

Adding these $n$ equations gives

$\sum_{i=1}^n b_i =(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i) - na_{n+1}$

You also know that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = -a_{n+1}$, so

$\sum_{i=1}^n b_i =-(n+1)a_{n+1} \\ \Rightarrow a_{n+1} = - \frac {\sum_{i=1}^n b_i }{n+1} \\ \Rightarrow a_i = b_i - \frac {\sum_{i=1}^n b_i }{n+1} $